# How to upload a mapping file to Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

In the old Crash reporting - there is easy way to upload. i didn't find it in the Crashlytics section

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Firebase update their docs: [see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)

There is no need anymore to manually upload mapping file.

1 - To preserve the info Crashlytics needs for readable crash reports, add the following lines to your config file:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

2 - To let Crashlytics automatically upload the ProGuard or DexGuard mapping file, remove this line from the config file (**app/proguard-rules.pro**):

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

> **For faster builds with ProGuard, exclude Crashlytics.** Add the
>   following lines to your config file:

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

Comment: I have proguard config file updated with mentioned rules. I see `:app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease`
`:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease`
during the build.
But all callstacks in firebase ui are obfuscated.

Comment: Actually you should NOT use -keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.** per https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports

Comment: `-printmapping mapping.txt` It should be removed from which config file?

Comment: @q126y `-printmapping <filename>` can be found in `app/proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: this is not good.  Google Play lets me upload the mapping.  I will not use -keep linenumbers etc in production code.

Comment: Not at all, ProGuard and DexGuard are both supported when the mapping file is uploaded at build.

Comment: How do I upload a mapping file on both Firebase Crashlytics and the Play Console? If I remove `-printmapping mapping.txt` to automatically upload it on Firebase, the file is not generated and I can't manually upload it on the Play Console.

Comment: My problem is i add all these line to proguard rules, most crashes show normally but some crashes show obfuscated.

Comment: Won't `-keepattributes SourceFile` somehow defeat the purpose of obfuscation?

Comment: The mapping file is generated and stored here (Windows): C:\Users\<username>\.crashlytics\com.crashlytics.tools\app-<id>\deobs

Comment: I did everything according to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android
I use Android Studio's Build -> Generate Signed APK. 
I can see in the logs here (~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log) that the deobfuscation file was uploaded sucessfully.

And, still my crashes in Firebase are obfuscated. Any ideas why?

Comment: last paragraph for faster builds with ProGuard in firbase docs is different: 
-keep class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.crashlytics.**

link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android

Comment: still getting the same error I follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)please help me for same

Comment: @BenjaminBisinger yes. you can verify this with APKTool or similar disassembler tools, look in the top of any supposedly "obfuscated" smali file, and it will contain the original source file name. to avoid this, you need to add `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile` to your proguard configuration. Crashlytics will still upload your mapping file and in fact it still gets the original source file name, but it's not stored in the APK

Answer (score 28):

Mike from Firebase here. Crashlytics in Firebase does not offer a way to upload mapping files outside of the build flow.

Comment: @itzhar would you be open to chatting about this more? Would love to understand the need for the manual upload outside of a build flow.

Comment: @MikeBonnell, when it doesn't work as expected it's much more difficult to understand what's going wrong. 
Since there is no any idnication that mapping was uploaded - you don't know if everything is good - you need to get first crash/exception to check it.
It's always better to have some control in own hands and have ability to fix it after if needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll chat with the team about making it easier to look into the build tooling logs that show whether or not the uploads were successful or not.

Comment: @MikeBonnell, our android app is written in Scala and we use sbt for building, so we are interesting in upload mapping.txt outside standard gradle build flow.

Comment: @MikeBonnell +1 on getting better visibility of what Crashlytics is doing here, it's supposed to just work but so many of us are completely stumped when it doesn't. Question re the mapping.txt file, the docs say to remove `-printmapping mapping.txt` so that the file isn't generated and Crashlytics can do its thing. I have never had that line in my pro file but mapping.txt is still generated and I have never seen deobfuscated crash reports. Any insight on this quirk? Cheers

Comment: There could be a variety of things happening @darnmason. If you want to look at logs, here's where they are, you just have to parse through them.  On Linux / Windows:
~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

On Mac:
~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Comment: Hmm I'm not seeing anything Crashlytics related in the Caches dir on Mac, a search for those dirs and file name also turned up blank, this was straight after running gradle assembleRelease

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on then. I'd recommend email support(at)fabric(dot)io with a link to this thread, and your app's build.gradle.

Comment: What if the prod build is being done by a machine with restricted internet access? Is there any ports or such that should be opened/configured?

Comment: Whitelist *.fabric.io and *.crashlytics.com on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: I just had Crashlytics report a crash and that was the first I knew the deobs file had failed to upload. On checking the crashlytics logs I now see `Crashlytics had a problem uploading the deobs file`. I re-ran the build and it uploaded OK this time, but it's a shame it fails in a non-obvious way and there's no way to manually upload. The existing crash isn't deobfuscated even though the re-run build has now uploaded it OK. I guess I just have to manually run retrace for this existing crash. In future I suppose I should tail the crashlytics log to make sure the upload works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will share it with the team.

Comment: I don't see an answer regarding the removal `-printmapping mapping.txt` @MikeBonnell

We're building and deploying APK to Google Play from a jenkins/docker pipeline.  We don't have any `printmapping` in our rules (custom or the default android), yet its created, and we archive it within Jenkins, but its NOT uploading to Crashlytics.  

Otherwise, the Triple-T plugin appears to be pushing it to Google Play console..

Comment: See [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37090826).

`mapping.txt` is generated automatically.. `printmapping` has gone through a stage, at least, where its not honored.  This doesn't reconcile well with the advice to remove the rule so that the plugin will upload it automatically

Comment: @MikeBonnell I don't see `-printmapping mapping.txt` anywhere, and still I've noticed obfuscated stuff of my app on crashes, on Firebase Crashlytics. How come? Also `mapping.txt` is generated anyway, so I actually upload it to Play Console website.

Comment: There are a variety of reasons, if you're hitting this after going through the changes and answers here, best to contact Firebase support.

Comment: @MikeBonnell It would be nice to have readable crash reports, just like we used to have on the old Firebase crash reporting system. You know, to make debugging actually possible, and stuff.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I landed up here because I think my stacktrace isn't correct in my app, so I was wondering if it was possible to upload it manually. I'm curious to hear how Crashlytics maps the auto-uploaded mapping.txt file with the installed version. If it's based on the version string, it might fail a lot of times for me, unfortunately..

Comment: Hey @Anigif the Gradle plugin generates a unique identifier so that our backend can identify your builds. This identifier is used to deobfuscate crashes and distribute the correct versions of your beta test builds. The identifier will be added to your res/values and looks like: <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">RANDOM_UUID</string> Reference: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#gradle-advanced-setup The version string doesn't matter.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I don't see the need for Google to get notified every time I run a (release) build.

Comment: @CarstenHagemann Sorry, I'm not following what you're saying. When a build happens, we generate a unique id in order to map back to the correct mapping file uploaded with that build.

Comment: @MikeBonnell This sentence "Crashlytics automatically uploads the mapping files for reach of your build variants." (source https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html) indicates to me that the mapping file is automatically uploaded every time I run a build. I don't think Google needs to know when and how often I run a build. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you want our service to de-obfuscate your stack traces, then we need to have the mapping file for the build. If you don't want to upload a mapping file for each build, you can disable it - https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#optimize-builds-when-you-re-not-proguarding-or-using-beta-by-crashlytics and https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#disable-crashlytics-for-debug-builds

Comment: I am unable to get it to work. I don't know how to find out what goes wrong. But the code remain obfuscated in the firebase console. 
I just want to upload my mapping.txt. Is there a way to manually to that?

Comment: There is not a manual upload at the moment. You could take a look at the build.log output to try and diagnose the issue. Also, see this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420776/crashlytics-not-uploading-mapping-file

Comment: We have automated build after every commit. So, mapping files are uploaded to firebase after every commit. It would be nice to control, when to upload mappings and when not.

Comment: Recently Firebase Crashlytics haven't uploaded my mapping file anymore. Not sure why but if I can upload mapping file myself it will be ok. If Google Play supports this feature then why FC doesnt't?

Comment: @MikeBonnell As you see from Juan Franco's answer above, linking the upload of mapping.txt to build process makes the process so hidden that developer is not in the loop anymore to "retry the upload properly". If a connection error occurs during the automatic upload, it's logged but Android Studio doesn't make it explicit for the developer. Without such a screen to intervene embedded in Android Studio, Firebase console (web) is always a better way if it offers manual upload option (after we release to Play Store).

Comment: @MikeBonnell please add option to specify where the google-services.json file is. It is very frustrating to need to create folders that only contain the google-services.json file. Or allow me to manually upload the mappings. I do not want to depend on the crashlytics plugin for gradle

Comment: Google, please just use mapping file uploaded to PlayStore to deobfuscate crash logs, simple and easy.

Comment: YES, it is very important on closed CI Servers with no access to Internet. Gradle dependencies are retrieved from local artifactories but the mapping cannot be uploaded automatically.

Comment: Also, the firebase keys are injected post build time, so we must disable the automatic upload because at that moment the app code won't even have the firebase project info to send the mapping.

Answer (score 8):

If you have followed the indications to enable the automatic upload then build the app and you still see the stack traces obfuscated in Firebase you should check the log files:

> On Linux / Windows:
>   /.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
>   On Mac:
>   ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Look for the latest entry with: `Uploading deobfuscation file`

And try to find the result of the operation like: `Deobfuscation file(s) uploaded` or  `Crashlytics had a problem uploading the deobs file` and you will get some hints about the cause.

Comment: I cannot understand that. If automatically uploading every time I build, then mapping will be different, right? (e.g. after publishing app, I changed code again so my new uploaded mapping will work with previousely production code?)

Comment: Looks like every build has a unique id that is used to match the code with the obfuscation file. I found that id on the .meta files.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `firebaseCrashlytics.enableMappingFileUpload` Gradle extension property to true in your app-level build.gradle file.

```
// To enable Crashlytics mapping file upload for specific product flavors:
  flavorDimensions "environment"
  productFlavors {
    staging {
      dimension "environment"
      ...
      firebaseCrashlytics {
        mappingFileUploadEnabled false
      }
    }
    prod {
      dimension "environment"
      ...
      firebaseCrashlytics {
        mappingFileUploadEnabled true
      }
    }
  }
```

for more details visit [Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, Firebase provided the option to enable mapping files manually

[Here you can find firebase CLI commands to upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?authuser=1&hl=en#crashlytics-commands)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Could you please also give an example of how to use the `crashlytics:mappingfile:upload` command? I don't get it what should I put to `--resource-file=` option?