# Is Proguard mapping file overwritten each time on Firebase Crashlytics a new release build is created?

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I am working on uploading the proguard mapping file to Firebase Crashlytics so that it can de-obfuscate the crash reports. What I am trying to understand is when and under what conditions is the mapping file uploaded to Firebase.

1. Each time I create a new release build, do I need to manually upload the mapping file using the `./gradlew uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease` task or is the mapping file uploaded automatically?
2. Are old mapping files overwritten by new ones for the same app version? For eg, I released v1.0 to play store and uploaded its mapping file to Firebase and for the next release continued working on the app and after changing code created release builds for internal testing without changing the version code - will this overwrite the original mapping file for v1.0 on Firebase?
3. Where can I check the status of the mapping file upload? I'm on mac os and I checked in `~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log` and this log file did not include the latest logs.
4. Where on Firebase can I check the uploaded mapping files?
5. How can I delete old mapping files on Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in Firebase Crashlytics, but I'll share my experiences, because it was a real headache seeing obfuscated stacktraces for a version of my app.

1. No, it is done automatically, it is part of the build process.
2. My experience is that it is not overwritten. The de-obfuscation seems to be fixed only after I've published a new version of the app.
3. Your best bet is to run the gradle task with `--info` and look for the status in the logs. The directory you mentioned does not seem to exist in the newer versions.
4. (and 5.) I don't think you can access that, [as it does not have a manual upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291552/4420543) anyway.